# Is there a significant difference between "rock" and "stone"?

Tags: word-usage

I found this pretty good small research, but I am still concerned about "regular usage" in life, say, when I am talking in the office, especially because of this comment:

> To me: Stone is something you can pick up with one hand (for
>   throwing). A rock takes two hands.

http://geologywriter.com/blog/stories-in-stone-blog/rock-or-stone-is-there-a-difference/

Comment: In the everyday American English that I speak, there is not that clear distinction. I can pick up a rock with one hand and throw it, and there are many stones too big or heavy to pick up. I've never thought about the difference. Maybe a matter of collocation(s).  It may be regional. A *boulder* is too big to pick up.

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5931/whats-the-difference-between-rock-and-stone

Comment: This seems to be a South African's take on sizing: http://forums.groundspeak.com/GC/index.php?showtopic=282646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the distinction you make is generally recognized. Lots of people talk about "throwing rocks" and also about "throwing stones".

A "stone" can be in its natural shape or it can have been cut into a desired shape, while "rock" indicates only the natural shape. That is, you can have a "tombstone" or "paving stones". If you say that you built a wall from "stone blocks", that will normally be understood to mean that they have been cut into a rectangular shape or whatever desired shape. But a wall built of "rocks" means in the shape you found them when you dug them up.

Dictionaries I checked listed them as synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, there is little difference between a rock and a stone, but in British English, there is. See these links: [rock](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rock) and [stone](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stone)

- rock: a material
- stone: a material
- a rock: a big, unshaped piece of material - a small boulder
- a stone: a small piece of material, or a shaped piece of material.

You can see the difference in terminology in the children's game that is called "rock, paper, scissors" in US and "paper, scissors, stone" in the UK.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throw%20rocks%2Cthrow%20stones&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrow%20rocks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrow%20stones%3B%2Cc0) indicates that the idea of "a rock" as something that is small enough throw started sometime in the 1860's.

Comment: Wow, that Ngram is interesting!

Comment: I'm BrE, and I've never heard of *paper, scissors, **stone***. It's always ***rock***, in my experience.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/rock-paper-scissors-and-scissors-paper.html. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper,_Scissors,_Stone, http://blogs.wsj.com/washwire/2015/03/06/poll-paper-scissors-stone-or-rock-paper-scissors/

Comment: I see your link cites the World RPS Society claiming *The Paper Scissors Stone Club was founded in London, England in 1842*, but separatedbyacommonlanguage admit themselves that this is "apparently fictional". Although I've never heard ***stone***, we did use to vary the *name* sequence to disorient the opponent. If you challenge someone to a game, they often open with the last option spoken in the name, so ***rock*** is a good bet for *your* first move. But I like [Gary Larson's take on it!](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/77/20/3d/77203db25b71710e97657d2f6652202f.jpg)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: One of the links I provided contains a survey, the results of which show there's roughly a 70/30 split between rock and stone. It doesn't give a geographic breakdown.

Comment: I didn't mean nobody in the world ever uses ***stone*** (or even ***boulder***) instead of ***rock*** here. I just meant I don't think there's any truth to the idea that "standard" usage is *US = **rock**, UK = **stone*** for the name of the game. Nor do I think there's any more general distinction between what ***rock*** and ***stone*** "mean" on either side of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is is no real distinction

> I threw a rock
>   I threw a stone

and most people will not make an explicit distinction

> [***Rocks in His Pockets***](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/allison-tate/the-rocks-in-his-pockets_b_4516678.html)
>   [***Stones In His Pockets***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stones_in_His_Pockets)

However, to geologists, a **stone is made of rock, but a rock is not made of stone**.

Rock is considered the material.
A stone is usually thought to be smallish and can be handled.

To possibly add some confusion to the naming scheme, there is [Stone Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Mountain) which certainly won't fit in your hand and is made of rock, and there is also [Rock City](http://www.seerockcity.com) which is a collection of rock formations.

Now, if you were to ask the difference between getting **rocked** or being **stoned**...

Comment: Likewise "the demonstrators stoned the police" and "the demonstrators rocked the police" :-)