# "Solid Like Stone" vs "Solid Like A Stone", which one would you prefer?

Tags: idioms, indefinite-article, zero-article

I found both forms (with and without "a") on the Internet. I don't know which one is more acceptable.

Is it an idiom?

https://wolfstone.za.com/blog/1-solid-like-stone-to-stone-like-solid

[image]

https://seekingalpha.com/article/2095473-suncor-energy-solid-like-a-stone

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solid%20like%20a%20stone%2C%20solid%20like%20stone%2C%20as%20solid%20as%20a%20rock%2C%20rock%20solid&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csolid%20like%20a%20stone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolid%20like%20stone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20solid%20as%20a%20rock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crock%20solid%3B%2Cc0) shows, neither expression is particularly common: in my opinion, neither is idiomatic either.

Reading the full text of the two articles, there are sufficient grammatical errors to make me doubt that the author or either article is a native English speaker.

There are two similar idiomatic expressions: "as solid as a rock" occurs more frequently, and "rock solid" is very common.

Note that there are differences between British and American English in the use of the words [rock and stone](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85817/is-there-a-significant-difference-between-rock-and-stone).

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

solid like stone (stone - mass noun)

solid like a stone (stone - countable noun)

**[** (as) solid as a rock= having a very strong basis, strongly built (not likely to break/fall) **]**